# Error in Updating a table using datetime as parameter in Stored procedure

Tags: sql, datetime

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE Mst_Attendance 
  SET FNLogged=@FNLogged,
   ANLogged=@ANLogged,LogTime=@LogTime,LogOuttime=@LogOuttime 
WHERE EmployeeId=@Employee_id AND Atdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @AtDate, 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
-- Convert(Datetime,@AtDate) 


SELECT * FROM Mst_Attendance where Atdate=@AtDate and EmployeeId=@Employee_id
```

Error occured near AS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AS` in that context is used to give an alias to a column or table; there is no sense in an `AS` here, since that isn't a select.

You have already specified a format via `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @AtDate, 101)`, but this also seems odd; dates are not strings. If you are matching on a `datetime` - keep everything as a `datetime`.

If you are actually trying to remove the time portion (leaving just a date), either a: don't send the time (cut it at the caller), or b: do something like:

```
set @date = cast(floor(cast(@date as float)) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `AS [MM/DD/YY]` snippet.  You don't need it, and it's not valid inside a WHERE clause.

And what in the world are you doing storing dates as strings in your database?  That's just a bad idea.  Are you trying to truncate the time portion?